# Display an Image that has to be resized in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, resize

Hi so i currently have a small image (about 100x160) as a NSData Attribute in my CoreData model.

i display all entities in a TableView. The UIImageView in a single Cell has only a size of 50x80. just dropping the image into this frame looks a bit pebbly.

what would be the best solution to display this image in my tableViewCell? resize it on-the-fly in my cellForRowAtIndexPath? probably this will lead up my tableview to become a bit laggy.

resize it on create and save it in my coredata entity (or probably on disk)?

thank you! please leave a comment if something is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to crop/resize the image. Following is the code to crop the image as per the required frame.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // do something......
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:(nsdata)]; // nsdata will be your image data as you specified.
        // To crop Image
        UIImage *croppedImage = [self imageByCropping:img] toRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 80)];

       // To resize image
        UIImage *resizedImage = [self resizeImage:img width:50 height:80];
    }
```

**Crop Image:**

```
    - (UIImage*)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
       CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
       UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
       return cropped;
    }
```

**Resize Image:**

```
    -(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(int)width height:(int)height 
    {
        CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
        CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);
        alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;
        CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef), 4 * width, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), alphaInfo);
        CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
        CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
        UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];   
        return result;  
    }
```

You can go with either of ways.

Comment: my problem is not how to resize it, but SHOULD i resize it while scrolling.

Comment: Yes, you should. And once you cache the resized image, you can refer the image from cache instead of each time to resize it.

Comment: the strange thing is. scrolling fast through my TV displays the wrong images in this columns. sometimes they are right (on first load) scrolling normally feels sometimes right and scrolling fast displays the wrong image in some cells. any idea why this happens ?

Comment: Are you using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier? And also set unique tag for each UIImageView.

Comment: i do use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. what is a unique tag? for each cell a own identifier?

Comment: For each cell an unique identifier that should not be repeat for any other cell and same with UIImageView.

Comment: what gets cached with the cellidentifier? because my labels of course all work without extra cell identifiers

Comment: Instead of resizing an image every time you can cache the resized image so that once resized image can be used again without any resizing process.